# Uncaught TypeError: calc.init(...).add is not a function

Tags: javascript, object

I have some task, to do function-constructor that creates a calculator object with method.
`init()`, `add()`, `mul()`, `div()`, `sub()`
My code:

```js
const calc = new Calculator();
console.log(
  calc
  .init(2)
  .add(2)
  .mul(3)
  .div(4)
  .sub(2).result // 1
);

calc.alert();

function Calculator() {
  let result = 0;

  this.alert = function() {
    setTimeout(() => alert(result), 5000);
  };

  this.init = function(i) {
    return result = i;
  };

  this.add = function(i) {
    return result += i
  };

  this.mul = function(i) {
    return result = result * i;
  };

  this.div = function(i) {
    return result = result / i;
  };

  this.sub = function(i) {
    return result = result - i;
  };
}
```

But I don`t understand, how to fix error.

Comment: The `add` and other methodsd just return a number, so they aren't [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). You should probably `return this` in your methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
const calc = new Calculator();
console.log(
  calc
  .init(2)
  .add(2)
  .mul(3)
  .div(4)
  .sub(2).result // 1
);

calc.alert();

function Calculator() {
  let result = 0;

  this.alert = function() {
    setTimeout(() => alert(result), 5000);
  };

  this.init = function(i) {
    this.result = i;
    return this;
  };

  this.add = function(i) {
    this.result += i;
    return this;
  };

  this.mul = function(i) {
    this.result = this.result * i;
    return this;
  };

  this.div = function(i) {
    this.result = this.result / i;
    return this;
  };

  this.sub = function(i) {
    this.result = this.result - i;
    return this;
  };
}
```

Comment: Output is still not correct.  You need to replace `this.result = result * i;` to `this.result = this.result * i;` and so on for all the function where you're directly referring to result

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to achieve Javascript Chaining Method Pattern here. Here I'm adding a better solution.

```js
var Calculator = function() {
  this.result = 0;
};

Calculator.prototype.init = function(i) {
  this.result = i;
  return this;
};

Calculator.prototype.add = function(i) {
  this.result = this.result + i;
  return this;
};

Calculator.prototype.mul = function(i) {
  this.result = this.result * i;
  return this;
};

Calculator.prototype.div = function(i) {
  this.result = this.result / i;
  return this;
};

Calculator.prototype.sub = function(i) {
  this.result = this.result - i;
  return this;
};

Calculator.prototype.alert = function() {
  setTimeout(() => alert(this.result), 5000);
  return this;
};

const calc = new Calculator();
console.log(
  calc
  .init(2)
  .add(2)
  .mul(3)
  .div(4)
  .sub(2).result // 1
);

calc.alert();
```

Comment: Interesting, i am just started to learn js, i will read about this. Thanks a lot.